# Polyfill for Math.max to make it useable for older browsers/systems

Tags: javascript, polyfills

I am using the Math.max function but it is not available on all devices and browsers. Is there a Polyfill or an other easy and fast way to solve this?

Comment: What device doesn't support this? Its been part of JavaScript since forever.. would be surprised that there is a browser that doesn't support it.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) says this is supported by all browsers.

Comment: Should be supported in all browser, `Math.max` has been a part of javascript since the first edition ?

Comment: It's trivial to write your own max function, if your mysterious device doesn't support `Math.max` for some reason.

Comment: i am developing an cordova app and there on a samsung galaxy s4 mini the function is not supportet

Comment: i used Math.max(...array)

Comment: Thats not a problem with `Math.max` but with destructuring (the 3 dots).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is not with `Math.max` as this has been supported since forever. It is with destructuring (`...` in `Math.max(...array)`). To get around that you can use older JavaScript which is quite likely supported.
Try :

`Math.max.apply(null, array);` (which does pretty much the same as `Math.max(...array)`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mozilla Math.max has full browser and mobile support.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 0):

See the following code:

```
if (!Math.max)
{
    Math.max = function()
  {
    var max = Infinity * -1;
    for (var index = 0; index < arguments.length; index++)
    {
        var val = arguments[index];
      if (val > max)
      {
        max = val;
      }
    }
    return max;
  };
}
```

DEMO: 
https://jsfiddle.net/1x3d1btf/3/